# How to add an image banner that appear on every page while printing?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to print a html document. This document contain multipage table. Now, I need a way to add an banner image at page-top on every page. I have tried with 'position:fixed', but this procedure overlaps my table rows.
I would be really grateful if anyone help me to find a solution.

Thanks in advance.

```
@media print{
 body div img{
 position: fixed;
 }
}
```

Comment: you trying to add page header ?? https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_layout_float

Comment: No. I want to add page header when printing. That means on print layout.

Comment: You could add a thead and hide it for screens

Comment: This is not my problem. I need a div that appear on every page when printing. Though position:fixed solve the problem, but it overlaps page content.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the image and hide it with `display:none` or other styles. And then in media print, show it with for ex `display:block`. That way it will be before the table ( or where you want it )

```css
img {
  display: none
}

@media print {
  img {
    display: block
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>table</td>
    <td>table</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>table</td>
    <td>table</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>table</td>
    <td>table</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I get the image by display:block. The problem is I need this this image in every page like a banner, which don't overlap with page content.

Comment: @NaimurRahaman well don't use position fixed. add it before all content. hide it. then show it on print